# unexpected reloc type 0x03

Tags: c++, g++, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries

I'm trying to execute a program compiled with my own library, but when i execute the program I get the following error:

```
./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: ../../lib-arm/libCustomLibrary.so: unexpected reloc type 0x03
```

That just happens with the Release execution, with the Debug execution all works fine.

Where do you think that may be the problem?

The CustomLibrary Library is linked with the following arguments:

```
-lSubLibrary -fPIC -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt
```

I attatch the lld unix library command output for my library.

```
ldd ../../lib-arm/libCustomLibrary.so 
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0x76e5d000)
libSubLibrary.so => ../../lib-arm/libSubLibrary.so (0x76e2d000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x76e10000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x76d3e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76ccd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76ca5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76b75000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x76b6a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76b4b000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f05000)
```

Comment: The symbol type `R_ARM_REL32` should not be a problem, except the runtime link-loader cannot handle it at the moment. Also see [arm: module: add support for R_ARM_REL32 relocations](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9527003/), which is a patch that was not applied to the kernel at the time. It is not clear to me if it has since been applied. I've also found `-fPIC` does not solve the problem; see Crypto++ Issue 846, [ARM and "unexpected reloc type 0x03" loading shared object](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/846)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-toolchain/2012-November/002939.html :

> Relocation type 3 is R_ARM_REL32 which is a static relocation not
>   allowed in shared objects.  How did you create the shared lib? Make
>   sure you compile all the code going into it with -fPIC.

In other words,  you are using `-fPIC` when linking your program, but perhaps not when building your shared library.

Comment: Thanks! I found that i was linking  `-lpthread` statically, i changed to link it dynamically and removed the `-fPIC` from the linker and it works perfect!

Comment: If you need to find the Symbol you can use `objdump -R mylib.so | grep R_ARM_REL32`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

```
./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: ../../lib-arm/libCustomLibrary.so: unexpected reloc type 0x03
```

I think you need to show the relevant source code for `libCustomLibrary.so`. You can see which symbol is causing the problem with:

```
LD_DEBUG=all ./a.out
```

After the verbose output, the last symbol mentioned will be the problem. For example, testing [Cryptogams SHA](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Cryptogams_SHA), which is hand written asm, in a shared object results in:

```
10419:     relocation processing: /home/test/libcryptopp-8.3.0.so.8 (lazy)
10419:     symbol=CRYPTOGAMS_armcaps;  lookup in file=/home/test/libcryptopp.so.8 [0]
10419:     binding file /home/test/libcryptopp.so.8 [0]: normal symbol `CRYPTOGAMS_armcaps'
/home/test/: error while loading shared libraries: /home/test/libcryptopp.so.8: unexpected reloc type 0x03
```

So I know the problem is with the `CRYPTOGAMS_armcaps` symbol. You can confirm with `objdump -r`. `R_ARM_REL32` is symbol type `0x03`.

```
$ objdump -r sha1-armv4.o

sha1-armv4.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
000004d0 R_ARM_REL32       CRYPTOGAMS_armcaps
```

Then you can go back to the source file and fix the problem with the symbol.

Also, from Crypto++ Issue 846, [ARM and "unexpected reloc type 0x03" loading shared object](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/846), I know it is not as simple as using `-fPIC`. Everything was built with `-fPIC` and the problem still surfaced.