# "unexpected reloc type 0x03" when loading shared library on ARM system

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, arm, dynamic-linking

I am trying to compile a shared library ([igraph](https://igraph.org/c/)) on Raspbian that will be used as a "plugin" to another program (to be specific, it will extend [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/), but I do not think this is relevant to the question).

This library can be compiled with [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) for a performance boost in some operations.  Without GLPK, everything works fine. But when I include GLPK, and try to load my shared library into the host application, I get the error:

```
unexpected reloc type 0x03
```

I am looking for tips that will help me find the cause of this error and eliminate it.

Some googling led me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474070/unexpected-reloc-type-0x03), which suggests that the problem may be that not everything is compiled with `-fPIC`. I double-checked that I do indeed compile everything with `-fPIC`. In the case of GLPK, I achieve this by passing `--with-pic` to the configure script.

What else may be causing this error?

I am looking for hints that will help me debug this. Debugging is painful on the Raspberry Pi as it takes hours to compile the project.

(Note: On x86_64 Linux I compile the project the same way and there are no issues. Thus I assume this must be at least ARM-specific.)

---

Note: This was originally posted on [RPi.SE](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) but received no attention at all.

Comment: That looks very much like a dynamic linking error, and in that case the `-fPIC` suggestion make sense.  Since that has not resolved the issue, and there are *two* libraries involved, chances are good that the issue is related to how you link them together.

Comment: I cannot answer confidently because I am not equipped to test for your target environment, but I suggest (1) make sure all versions of GLPK are uninstalled.  (2) Build GLPK with the `--disable-static` flag (`--with-pic` should not be necessary, but probably won't hurt).  (3) Install GLPK (`make install`).  (4) Build `igraph`, linking it against the GLPK shared library.